# Affdex AFDXDetector delegate functions are never called when using the camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, affdex-sdk

I’m having some trouble getting the [Affdex iOS SDK](http://developer.affectiva.com/ios/) to work with streaming input from the onboard camera. I’m using XCode 7.1.1 and an iPhone 5S. Here’s my initialization code:

```
let detector = AFDXDetector.init(delegate: self, usingCamera: AFDX_CAMERA_FRONT, maximumFaces: 1)
detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true)
detector.setDetectAllExpressions(true)
detector.maxProcessRate = 5.0
detector.licensePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sdk_kevin@sideapps.com", ofType: "license”)

if let error = detector.start() {
    log.warning("\(error)")
}
```

No error is produced by detector.start() and the app requests access to the camera the first time it is called, as expected. However, none of the delegate functions are ever called. I have tested with both AFDX_CAMERA_FRONT and AFDX_CAMERA_BACK.

I am able to process single images captured by the onboard camera as expected using the following:

```
let detector = AFDXDetector(delegate: self, discreteImages: true, maximumFaces: 1)
detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true)
detector.setDetectAllExpressions(true)
detector.licensePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sdk_kevin@sideapps.com", ofType: "license")

if let error = detector.start() {
    log.warning("\(error)")
}

detector.processImage(image)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be the declaration of the *detector* variable. The lifetime of that variable is only scoped for the function if you declare it inside of the function — it is deallocated when the function exits.

Make the variable an instance variable in the class; this guarantees its lifetime is for the life of the object that it is instantiated in, and the delegate functions should also be called.